# Having FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setUp and FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass tearDown java.lang.NullPointerException errors

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm using selenium 3.0.0-beta4 version. Tried to configure settings for geckoDriver on my project. I used Maven and TestNG along with java.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class GmailSignupAutomation {
    private WebDriver driver;
      private String baseUrl;

 @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
      public void setUp() throws Exception {System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D://software_/geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64/geckodriver.exe");

      DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
      capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
      **driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);**

        baseUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      }

@Test
      public void testGoogleAccountLoginForm() throws Exception {
        driver.get(baseUrl + "//SignUp?service=mail&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/?pc=topnav-about-en");
        driver.findElement(By.id("FirstName")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("FirstName")).sendKeys("HOSSAIN");
      }

@AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
      public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
      }
```

}

And here is the output:

1476438749160   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:39530 Oct 14, 2016 3:52:29 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession

INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end

1476438749613   mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path C:\Users\HOSSAI~1.MAH\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.e9aWwalq9rWK

1476438749656   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe

1476438749683   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:61519 Oct 14, 2016 3:52:32 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession

INFO: **Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection**

1476438752490   mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path C:\Users\HOSSAI~1.MAH\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.D6FkME6daU3V

1476438752499   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe

1476438752535   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:61527 Oct 14, 2016 3:52:37 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession

INFO: **Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol. 1476438757062**    mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path

C:\Users\HOSSAI~1.MAH\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.FHKHmYIM3lXI

1476438757069   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe

1476438757127   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:61557

[Utils] Attempting to create D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\Default suite\Default test.xml

[Utils]   Directory D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\Default suite exists: true

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setUp org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, browserName=firefox, version=, platform=ANY}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]

Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '3169782', time: '2016-09-29 10:24:50 -0700' System info: host: 'XYZ', ip: '101.140.178.123', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_102'

Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:80)    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:602)     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)  at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:247)     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:235)     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:230)     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:226)     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:124)     at SeleniumAutomation.GoogleSignupAutomation.GmailSignupAutomation.setUp(GmailSignupAutomation.java:39)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:216)   at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:143)   at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:169)     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)  at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:746)    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:600)   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)  at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1264)    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1189)     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1104)    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1076)  at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:152)     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:57)

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass tearDown java.lang.NullPointerException   at SeleniumAutomation.GoogleSignupAutomation.GmailSignupAutomation.tearDown(GmailSignupAutomation.java:55)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:216)   at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:143)   at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeAfterClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:217)  at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:115)  at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:746)    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:600)   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)  at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1264)    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1189)     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1104)    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1076)  at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:152)     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:57)

## SKIPPED: testGoogleAccountLoginForm

```
Default test
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
```

## Configuration Failures: 2, Skips: 0

## =============================================== Default suite Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1 Configuration Failures: 2, Skips: 0

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@3b938003: 50 ms [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@475e586c: 12 ms [Utils] Attempting to create D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\old\Default suite\toc.html [Utils]   Directory D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true [Utils] Attempting to create D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\old\Default suite\Default test.properties [Utils]   Directory D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true [Utils] Attempting to create D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\old\Default suite\index.html [Utils]   Directory D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true [Utils] Attempting to create D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\old\Default suite\main.html [Utils]   Directory D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true [Utils] Attempting to create D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\old\Default suite\groups.html [Utils]   Directory D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true [Utils] Attempting to create D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\old\Default suite\classes.html [Utils]   Directory D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true [Utils] Attempting to create D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\old\Default suite\reporter-output.html [Utils]   Directory D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true [Utils] Attempting to create D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\old\Default suite\methods-not-run.html [Utils]   Directory D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true [Utils] Attempting to create D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\old\Default suite\testng.xml.html [Utils]   Directory D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true [Utils] Attempting to create D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\old\index.html [Utils]   Directory D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\old exists: true [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@780cb77: 95 ms [Utils] Attempting to create D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\junitreports\TEST-SeleniumAutomation.GoogleSignupAutomation.GmailSignupAutomation.xml [Utils]   Directory D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\junitreports exists: true [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@3a079870: 106 ms [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@17c1bced: 241 ms [Utils] Attempting to create D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\testng-failed.xml [Utils]   Directory D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output exists: true [Utils] Attempting to create D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\Default suite\testng-failed.xml [Utils]   Directory D:\Projects\Automation\GoogleSignupAutomation\test-output\Default suite exists: true [TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 8 ms

Comment: Edited the coding section for adding updates.
After debugging "driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities)", found that:
1. The step threw Invoker.class
2. Opened 3 firefox blank windows

Answer (score 1):

i think After Setting the Driver path, u need to set the DesiredCapabilities to MarionetteDriver as shown in the Below Code. Works for me Fine.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                            capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
                            Driver = new MarionetteDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: What do you mean by setting the Driver path? I mean did you mean to set geckoDriver or MarionetteDriver? 
Also, using MarionetteDriver tells that the constructor is depricated in java. 
I used your suggested lines just after System.setProperty() of my coding. But the errors occurred.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the following steps:

1. Download the marionette driver
2. Unarchive it to a folder of your choice
3. In your code set the "webdriver.gecko.driver" property to the location of the .exe
4. Use the MarionetteDriver
5. rename the file to ‘wires.exe’ and
   add it to your path.

I did rename it to wires.exe, mainly to keep the code consistent so I wouldn’t have to update the code every time I change the version of the marionette driver.

But I didn’t add it to the path. I’d rather control that in the code when the option is provided.

Firefox 47 and above my code looks like this:

```
String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String marionetteDriverLocation = currentDir + "/tools/marionette/wires.exe";
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", marionetteDriverLocation);
WebDriver driver = new MarionetteDriver();
```

You can check the code update from the following github sample code: https://github.com/kumrunnaharkeya/sample-automation-selenium